# Django 1.8 model default value

Tags: python, django

I have a model that look like this:

```
from django.db import models

def default_pic():
    return "/static/images/default.png"

class Album(models.Model):
    album_id = models.CharField(max_length=128, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    album_art = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=default_pic())
```

So, according to [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#default) the default value for `album_art` should be `/static/images/default.png`, however the setted value is `default`

By the way I tried both syntax :

```
album_art = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=default_pic())
```

and

```
album_art = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=default_pic)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know that it is not wotking? If you instantiate an object and get the value for album_art, the value will be the value you set

Comment: By checking the value of `album_art` field in django admin or even in mysql. In my HTML code too. I call `{{ album.album_art }}` in a template, it gives "default" instead of "/static/images/default.png"

Comment: The `default` is used by django to attribute the value you set at the time you instantiate the model. So, if you go to shell, and do `var = Album()` , the `album_art` will be `"/static/images/default.png"` . Or if you do `Album.objects.create..` . But, you won't find that in MySQL board for example

Comment: In my HTML code too. I call {{ album.album_art }} in a template, it gives "default" instead of "/static/images/default.png"